# Charset of Textfile stored with file_put_contents() is missinterpretated

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

To prepare a download of some HTML `contenteditable`, as plain text file, I do following :

1. Send the html `contenteditable`, which inherits other html elements, through Ajax to a server side script `prepareDownload.php`.
2. There I create a new DOMDocument : `$doc = new DOMDocument();`
3. Then I do : `$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $_POST["data"]);`
4. Then I am looking for text contents in certain elements and assemble it in `$plainText`
5. Finally I write `$plainText` to disk with : `file_put_contents($txtFile,  $plainText, LOCK_EX);`

So far it works … but when I open the textfile the special characters like the German `Ä` are a mess.

To find out where the problem might be generated I place some `print_r()` commands on several stages in the php script and look into the browsers console whats coming back.
Until the point where I write `$plainText` with `to disk file_put_contents()` everything is perfect. Looking into the stored text file then, characters are a mess.

Now I assume that `file_put_contents()` misinterprets the given charset. But how to tell `file_put_contents()` that it should interpret (not encode) it as UTF-8 ?

**EDIT:**
As a test to find out more I replaced the explizit statement :

```
$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $_POST["data"])
```

with

```
$doc->loadHTML($_POST["data"])
```

The character `ä` in the file still looks weired, but different. The hexdump now looks like this :

`0220: 20 76 69 65 6C 2C 20 65 72 7A C3 A4 68 6C 74 20   viel, erz..hlt`

Now `ä` has two points (two bytes) and is hex `C3 A4`. What kind of encoding is this ?

Comment: How are you opening the file exactly? Very likely whatever program you're opening it with simply doesn't pick the right encoding.

Comment: I am not opening a file from disk. I receive content through Ajax. Then I write the content to diks as above written. The content I receive is okay.

Comment: *"but when I open the textfile the special characters..."* – please be extremely explicit what exactly you're doing to "open" the file.

Comment: well I open the file with a simple texteditor. And I open it in UTF-8 charset. I must add that I work on a mac and develop with XAMPP locally

Comment: Open it in a hex editor and have a look what the hex representation of the content is. Try to locate an "Ä" and look at its hex value. If its `C3 84`, the file is properly UTF-8 encoded and your text editor is the only problem here. Otherwise, let us know what it is.

Comment: Well the example is an `ä` . Here is some hex data     0220: 76 69 65 6C 2C 20 65 72 7A E4 68 6C 74 20 73 63  viel, erz.hlt sc
    In the readable text it is the point

Comment: So ä is `E4`, which is indeed ISO-8859-1 encoded. It's hard to help you with specifics without seeing the entire chain of events though...

Comment: Ok, but where is ISO-8859-1 coming from. All the chain from the website down to the file on the server supposed to be UTF-8. Its declared in the HTML Header, i feed the `loadHTML()` method with a preceeded UTF declaration. And finally when I look in my browser console everything is looking good. Why not in the saved file on disk ?

Comment: ä as `C3 A4` is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: **Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing**. Stack Overflow is not a "forum". You have the wrong expectations. There is no "zensorship" [sic] going on here. The very fact that he was able to edit means he has the privilege to do so.